# Using Variable in MySql Regex Query

Tags: mysql, regex

I am attempting to search multiple columns for tags and returning the type.

Below is a simplified version of my query.

```
set @item_1 = '(Tag1|Tag2|Tag3|Tag4)(,| |$)',
    @item_2 = '(Tag5|Tag6|Tag7|Tag8)(,| |$)';
select
  case
    when tags_1 regexp @item_1
      then 'Item_1'
    when tags_2 regexp @item_1
      then 'Item_1'
    when tags_1 regexp @item_2
      then 'Item_2'
    when tags_2 regexp @item_2
      then 'Item_2'
    else 'Uncategorised'
  end type
from my_table
order by date desc
```

Is there any way to set the tags as a variable and the use them within regex. I have tried the above and am getting the error below.

```
[ERROR in query 2] Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'regexp'
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your table collation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `COLLATE` every after `REGEXP` expression.

```
set @item_1 = 'Tag1|Tag2|Tag3|Tag4',
    @item_2 = 'Tag5|Tag6|Tag7|Tag8';
select
  case
    when tags_1 regexp concat(@item_1, '(%)(,|$)') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      then 'Item_1'
    when tags_2 regexp concat(@item_1, '(%)(,|$)') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      then 'Item_1'
    when tags_1 regexp concat(@item_2, '(%)(,|$)') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      then 'Item_2'
    when tags_2 regexp concat(@item_2, '(%)(,|$)') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      then 'Item_2'
    else 'Uncategorised'
  end type
from my_table
order by date desc;
```

Another work-around is to change your table collation to **latin1 - default collate** / **Schema Default**. You do not anymore have to specify `COLLATE`.